# how to insert multiple fields in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a table that has :

role

name

age

like this.

```
<input type="text" name="role[]" value="father">
<input type="text" name="role[]" value="mother">

<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Anton">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Shirley">

<input type="text" name="age[]" value="53">
<input type="text" name="age[]" value="49">
```

how ever I can only save the role[] only.

here is my code :

```
foreach(Input::get('role') as $i)
            {


                $data = new Family_background();

                $data -> role = $i;
                $data -> name = Input::get('name');
                $data -> age = Input::get('age');
                $data -> save();


            }
```

p.s I suck at this.

any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(Input::get('role') as $i => $role)
{
    $data = new Family_background();

    $data->role = $role;
    $data->name = Input::get('name')[$i];
    $data->age = Input::get('age')[$i];
    $data->save();
}
```